# Difference of implementation between tensorflow softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits and sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: python, tensorflow

I recently came across tensorflow `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, but I can not figure out what the difference on the implementation is compared to `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am answering a bit late, but better late than never. So I had the exact same doubt and the answer was there in tensorflow documentation. The answer is and I quote:

> [softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2): Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in which the classes are mutually exclusive (each entry is in exactly one class).
>   [sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits): Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in which each class is independent and not mutually exclusive

edit: Thought I should add that while the classes are mutually exclusive, their probabilities need not be. All that is required is that each row of labels is a valid probability distribution. which is not the case in `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` in which the `label` is a vector containing only the index of the true class.

I am also adding the links to the documentation. Hope this answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` first calculates [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) and then a cross entropy, whereas `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` first calculates [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) and then cross entropy.

Answer (score 1):

the major difference between sigmoid and softmax is that softmax function return result in terms of probability which is kind of more inline with the ML philosophy. Sum of all outputs from softmax result to 1. This is turn tells you how confident the network is about the answer.

Whereas, sigmoid outputs are discreet. Its either correct or incorrect. You would have to write code to calculate the probability yourself.

As far as performance of the network goes. Softmax generally gives better accuracy than sigmoid. But, it also highly dependent on other hyper parameters also.